# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dataValues') error when retrieving user-specific posts using GET request, but works with POST request

Tags: express, rest, post, get, postman

**API route:**

`router.get('/post/user/:id?', verifyToken, getPostByUserId);`

When I define **GET** route like this, it is working just fine for getting post with user id provided but when I fetch route `/user` it is supposed to give data of the logged in `user id` which is available in `req.user` after token verification, but it gives error:

`Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dataValues')`

If it is data size related issue why getting same user data is fetched while providing id but not while getting user id

,but it never goes inside of `getPostByUserId` function as I try logging the console. I also tried creating seperate route `/post/me` to fetch posts of logged in user but result is same.

But when I changed the **GET** to **POST** everything works just fine.

Why is this error occuring ?

`getPostByUserId`

```js
getPostByUserId = async (req, res) => {
    let userId;
    if (req.params.id) {
      userId = req.params.id;
    } else if (req.user) {
      userId = req.user.id;
    } else {
      return res.send(message.error('Missing user id!'));
    }
    let { page = 0, limit = 10 } = req.query;
    page = parseInt(page);
    limit = parseInt(limit);
    const offset = page * limit;
    const limitPerPage = parseInt(limit);
    try {
      const posts = await models.posts.findAll({
        where: { user_id: userId },
        limit: limitPerPage,
        offset,
        attributes: { exclude: ['user_id'] },
        include: [{
          model: models.users,
          attributes: ['handle']
        }]
      });
      // include pagination info to response
      const response = {
        posts,
        page,
        limit
      };
      return res.send(message.success(response));
    } catch (error) {
      res.send(message.error(error.message));
    }
  };
```

I tried adding seperate route for both getting post by user id and getting post by logged in user, it works for getting post with id in param but not in getting user by logged in user

`router.get('/post/me', verifyToken, getPostByLoggedInUser);`

```js
getPostByLoggedInUser = async (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.user.id;
    let { page = 0, limit = 10 } = req.query;
    page = parseInt(page);
    limit = parseInt(limit);
    const offset = page * limit;
    const limitPerPage = parseInt(limit);
    try {
      const posts = await models.posts.findAll({
        where: { user_id: userId },
        limit: limitPerPage,
        offset,
        attributes: { exclude: ['user_id'] },
        include: [{
          model: models.users,
          attributes: ['handle']
        }]
      });
      // include pagination info to response
      const response = {
        posts,
        page,
        limit
      };
      return res.send(message.success(response));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.send(message.error(error.message));
    }
  };
```

which still gives error like this in GET request:
`Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dataValues')`

I tried also using `console.log` on start of function like this

```js
getPostByLoggedInUser = async (req, res) => {
    console.log('\n\n get post by logged in user');
    const userId = req.user.id;
    // ...rest of code
```

it never throwed this `console.log` in terminal console.

But all the error disappear after I chaned **GET** to **POST** in every case.

Comment: After I removed the `node_modules` folder and installed the packages again with `npm i ` it is now working fine, but I want to know what was happened before causing that kind of issue.